# Show subtitle to corresponding video using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a subtitle file, structured as follows:

```
{ id: '54',
    startTime: '00:03:46,572',
    endTime: '00:03:53,160',
    text: 'Hello this is a text' 
 },
 { id: '55',
    startTime: '00:03:53,160',
    endTime: '00:03:58,799',
    text: 'To be precise, the subtitle file of a movie' 
 },
```

I would now like to go through this file and show the subtitles whenever the respective time is reached in a playing video. I do know roughly how I would realise something like this in javascript, but I am wondering how to do it using React & Redux.

Could I somehow save the time of the video playing in my state and then, everytime that changes, react accordingly with my subtitles? Or what would you suggest? I would very much welcome some code / examples.

Answer (score 0):

This question feel way too general.

The way I would approach the problem is following. Hopefully it gives you a general idea.

I presume subtitles is an array of objects and ids correspond to array indexes.

```
const initialState = {
  activeSubtitleId: 0,
  // Here are your subtitles
  subtitles: [],
}
```

Then setup a reducer listening to one action

```
export const videoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SYNC_SUBTITLES: {
      const { videoTime } = action.payload

      const activeSubtitleId = state.subtitles
        .filter(subtitle => subtitle.startTime >= videoTime && subtitle.endTime <= videoTime)[0].id

      return { ...state, activeSubtitleId }
    }
  }
}

export default videoReducer
```

Last missing piece is an action SYNC_SUBTITLES

```
export const SYNC_SUBTITLES = "SYNC_SUBTITLES"

export const syncSubtitles = (videoTime) => ({
  type: SYNC_SUBTITLES,
  payload: {
    videoTime
  }
})
```

To wire it all up you need to connect redux store to your component, and extract state.subtitles[state.activeSubtitleId]. You might some memoizing library for this, for example Reselect. Depending of how often will you like to sample the time.

Now you can display the correct subtitles.

To keep them synced, you need to dispatch SYNC_SUBTITLES action from your component with defined tick frequency. You can use setTimeout for this, or built-in videoplayer tick emitter.

So the connect might look like this. Pretty silly, but working.

```
@connect((state, props) => {
  const activeSubtitleId = state.activeSubtitleId;
  const subtitles = state.subtitles;

  return {
    activeSubtitle: subtitles[activeSubtitleId]
  }
}, {
  syncSubtitles
})
```